# What do you call these large signs hung from the ceilings?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call these large signs hung from the ceilings? We often find these at the airport, sometimes, instead of one large sign, we have 3 large ones next to each other with the directions to various places. Is there a specific word for these, I would be very much surprised if they were just called signs.

Comment: I think just signs or banners. You could be more specific and say “directional/informational sign.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We normally call them signs, though you can also say airport terminal signs or direction/directional signs at the terminal.